# gradle.properties settings not considered

Tags: gradle

As a starter in gradle I am converting a project from maven to gradle. When running tests I get an `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. If I add

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs = ['-Xmx2g']
}
```

to `build.gradle` then it works. However, if that is configured only in `gradle.properties` as `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2g` then it doesn't.

Same for the encoding. There is one test which is only running successful if `GRADLE_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` is set. But if I set `systemProp.file.encoding=UTF-8` in `gradle.properties` it doesn't.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is described in the Gradle DSL documentation for the [Test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) task.

> Test are always run in (one or more) separate JVMs.

Whatever you configure in `gradle.properties` environment variable applies to the Gradle JVM process only.

Maximum heap size is configured like you did via `jvmArgs` or, preferably, via [maxHeapSize](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:maxHeapSize).

Regarding file encoding & `GRADLE_OPTS`, I don't have a definite answer. My best guess is that it has just not been implemented this way. You can set the file encoding on a per project basis for compilation tasks like this:

```
tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

From: [Gradle Goodness: Set Java Compiler Encoding](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/06/gradle-goodness-set-java-compiler.html?m=1)